# Cosmos DB (Mongo DB API) performance of querying across partitions bad

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I need your help in solving the issue wrt cross partition query, I have collection (mongo db api) which stores records with the partition type as “applicationType”. It works fine when I know my application type which basically satisfies 75% of my users but there are few strategic customers who want us to provide data based on manufacturer which is not the part of partition. When I query without the Application Type, queries perform really bad.

Need your suggestion in resolving this.  For your reference, please find below the sample of the collection we store

```js
{
               "_id" : ObjectId("5ad5d6b7529cd2007ba73bc8"),
               "applicationType" : "Highbay",
               "name" : "X",
               "subSeries" : "X1",
               "fullSeriesName" : "C1X", 
               "manufacturer": "cre"
               ...
               ...
               ...

}
,
{
               "_id" : ObjectId("5ad5d6b7529cd2007ba73bc8"),
               "applicationType" : "AreaLight",
               "name" : "X",
               "subSeries" : "X1", (mongo db 
               "fullSeriesName" : "C1X", 
               "manufacturer": "cre"
               ...
               ...
               ...
```

Comment: Please edit your question with more details. For instance: What do you consider "bad" performance (and what is "good" performance within a partition)? Is it a latency issue? Is it a Request Unit cost issue? What does your query look like? How much data are you searching through? Are any of your search-specific properties indexed? There might not be any "right" answer to this, since data-modeling isn't an exact thing - it's application-specific. Also, it's dependent on your specific read & write patterns (which is why I was mentioning all the unknowns in your question).

Answer (score 0):

This is a common pattern for partitioned data stores.

The solution for Mongo users is to use [Change Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-change-streams) and write all of the data into another collection using a different partition (shard) key, or pre-compute whatever values you need to answer these queries as in-partition.

You'll need some compute to host the process when you do coll.watch and some other caveats that are outlined in the link above.

One other thing too is you will need to measure the cost of using Change Streams versus the cost of just doing the cross-partition queries. Generally speaking, this solution is more cost efficient for high volume queries. Something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

you could create two different collections one for regular customers partitioned by "ApplicationType" and for strategic customers partitioned by "manufacturer".